# How can I convert from a Task<Generic.List<T>> to a Generic.IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, async-await, blazor

This is my parent component:

```
private IEnumerable<InventoryListDTO> InventorySelected { get; set; } = new List<InventoryListDTO>();

InventorySelected = _inventoryRepository.GetForList(inventorySelectDTO);
```

This is my implementation:

```
public async Task<List<InventoryListDTO>> GetForList(T_IFS_InventorySelectDTO InventorySelection)
```

And this is what is returned:

```
IEnumerable<InventoryListDTO> itemsMapped = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<T_IFS_Inventory>, IEnumerable<InventoryListDTO>>(query);
{ async calls to modify data in itemsMapped }
return itemsMapped.ToList();
```

I need the implementation to be async.  Maybe I am not using the correct types but the error I am getting is:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<ISInventory_Models.InventoryListDTO>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ISInventory_Models.InventoryListDTO>'
```

I'm fine with returning an IEnumerable or a List but it must be async. I had this working until I tried to make it async and now I'm pretty confused. I have tried too many things to list but I can't quite get it right and I was hoping someone could assist. Please comment if you need additional information. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah, your code returns https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1?view=net-7.0

Comment: `await` the `GetForList` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `await` the `Task` like this within the context of an async method.  In your case probably `OnInitializedAsync` as it's in a component:

```cs
private IEnumerable<InventoryListDTO> InventorySelected = Enumerable.Empty<InventoryListDTO>();

protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
   InventorySelected = await _inventoryRepository.GetForList(inventorySelectDTO);
}
```

You can also assign an empty `Enumerable` on initialization rather that building out a List.

Comment: Ta.  That's what comes when you type code into a textbox!  Fixed.

Comment: Thank you.  I spend hours on things and then it is something simple. Please accept my gratitude.